# How can a bool variable accept stored text without error, but in other cases there is an error?

Tags: c++

When I write `bool x = "hallo"`, there is no error. It is assumed that the non-zero value is implicitly converted into a Boolean value, which represents the number 1:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool x = "hallo;
    cout << x << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

But in other cases, there is an error, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string text = "hallo";
    bool x = text;
    cout << x << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this different?

An error should not occur, because it is assumed that the text value is considered a non-zero value, so output should be 1.

Comment: _" ... the text value is considered a non-zero value ..."_ Huh what please??

Answer (score 5):

You are not seeing the behaviour that you think you are seeing. The content of the strings is not being tested.

In `bool x="hallo";`, `"hallo"` is not a `std::string`. It is a [String Literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), a `const` array of `char`s of exactly the right length. Via [array-to-pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/4581301) the address of the string literal can be used to initialize a boolean. Since the array cannot have a null address it will always be a non-zero value and always result in a boolean value of true regardless of the content of the string literal.

There is no implicit conversion between `std::string` and `bool`, so `bool x=text;` cannot compile.

Comment: Side note: [A similar gotcha](https://godbolt.org/z/hhhToTqfa) Converting the string literal to a `bool` is preferred over the more intuitive `string`.